# Reads a file whose location might be specified by user in Sonar

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am getting Sonar vulnerability on below piece of code. How can I solve this vulnerability?

### code

```
public static final String getFilePath(String configFileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File configFile = new File(FilenameUtils.getName(configFileName));
        if (configFile.exists()) {
            return configFile.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        URL url = ConfigHelper.class.getClassLoader().getResource(configFileName);
        if (url != null) {
            return url.getPath();
        }
        logger.error("Failed to find the file on classpath:" + configFileName);
        return null;
    }
```

### Error

[image]

Comment: Is `configFileName` derived from user input? This is a potential vulnerability, if users can't control the path this is a false positive

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is this method meant to do? What it *actually* does is:

- Takes an input argument which may contain a full path, e.g. `"/path/to/file.ext"`
- Throws away the path (using FileNameUtils), getting just "file.ext"
- Checks to see if the file exists in the current directory.

So if the user does `cd /some/dangerous/directory` and then runs your application, even if your method is passed `"/a/safe/directory/file.ext"`, if the file `file.ext` exists in `/some/dangerous/directory` then your method will return `"/some/dangerous/directory/file.ext"`. If the user copies a virus and names it "file.ext" in that dangerous directory, you might be in trouble.